# VS Code cannot open source file "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, cmake

I am trying to include OpenCV library for my project. But VS Code keeps showing me the error:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/Users/erenerogullari/Desktop/School/DIP/dip02/main.cpp). 
cannot open the source file 'opencv2/opencv.hpp'.
```

even though I added it to my include path in 'settings.json'.

Here is my 'main.cpp' file:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> // Error is shown here
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char **argv){...}
```

And my 'setting.json' for C/C++ extension in VS Code:

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": ["${default}", "/Users/eren/opencv-4.5.0/include/opencv2"]
}
```

I built the project using CMake Tools for VS Code. Here is my 'CMakeLists.txt' file if it's helpful in any way:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project( dip2 LANGUAGES CXX )

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )


add_library(code 
    Dip2.cpp
    Dip2.h
)

set_target_properties(code PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)


target_link_libraries(code
    PUBLIC
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)

target_include_directories(code PUBLIC ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})


add_executable(main 
    main.cpp 
)

set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)

target_link_libraries(main 
    PRIVATE
        code
)

target_include_directories(main PUBLIC ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})


add_executable(unit_test 
    unit_test.cpp 
)

set_target_properties(unit_test PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)

target_link_libraries(unit_test 
    PRIVATE
        code
)

target_include_directories(unit_test PUBLIC ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.51.1 on macOS 11.0.1. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need a target_include_directories() because you don't have opencv installed in your system location.

Comment: Changing it to target_link_libraries(code -L/Users/eren/opencv-4.5.0/include) didn't help if that's what you meant

Comment: The -L part is wrong. It should be `target_include_directories(code ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})` and you may have to do that for the main and unit_test targets as well.

Comment: I've added it to all of them as you recommended but it's still giving the same error.

Comment: Maybe you need to reconfigure at the CMake stage. Not sure how you are using it in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: What is the result of command `pkg-config --modversion opencv` on terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by reinstalling OpenCV with homebrew and adding the path to included paths in C/C++ extension:

```
{
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
    "${default}",
    "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.0_5/include/opencv4"
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you use this path `"/Users/eren/opencv-4.5.0/include/opencv2"` and you are using the header as <opencv2/core.hpp> you are actually searching for `"/Users/eren/opencv-4.5.0/include/opencv2/opencv2/core.hpp"` which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34324559)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the your Project Settings to 64Bits.

Also check the Project/properties (C/C++)General/Additional Include Directories),  setting path to C:\opencv\build\include (root where the opencv2 lives).

Must be intact to work on opencv2 directory root.